# Partially successfully write a vector<uint8_t> object into file in binary format

Tags: c++, binary, ostream

I run into the code as follow:

```
class A{
std::vector<std::uint8_t> vec;
std::uint32_t i;

... // init vec and i
public:
void w(ostream &os){
    os.write((const char*)&i,sizeof(i));
    os.write((const char*)&vec[0],sizeof(vec[0])*vec.size());
}
};
```

I called "w" through ofstream

```
A a();
std::ofstream ofs("file");
a.w(ofs);
ofs.close();
```

vec stores a sequence of character, however, file contains binary value of "i" and not binary format sequence of characters.

How can I write vec into binary format?

Comment: open file with `std::ios::binary`

Comment: How are you checking the file? If the vector contains characters, what you write will be the raw data of those characters, most likely ASCII encoded. If you look at them in an editor which is able to read text then it will display it as text. Look at it in a hex-editor instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I checked it through vim and cat command. Is this due to editor ? Are these characters actually written in binary format:-)?

Comment: If your system uses [ASCII encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) (which is very likely) the character `'A'` is represented by the integer number `65`. So when your editor reads an integer-byte `65` it will think it is the character `'A'`.

Comment: It should contain the binary value of i. Maybe post the hex dump of the first 4 bytes, actual and expected. However, the real question is "are you reading it the same way you are writing it?" Oh yeah and what knivil said in the first comment -- that's a common problem on windows systems, which would be obvious if we see the actual numbers involved.